# Multiplying a float by -1.0 casts the number to an int

Tags: php, casting, decimal

When I have a decimal and try to make it negative, it converts the number to an integer. In the test code, `$myl->point_spread` is `1.5`.

```
echo "Point spread: " . ($myl->point_spread * -1.0) . " and " . $myl->point_spread . "\n";
```

Here is the output:

> Point spread: -1 and 1.5

I have also tried `-$myl->point_spread` and `0 - $myl-point_spread` to no avail.

So what gives? How can I obtain the correct value of `-1.5` that I am expecting?

Comment: Doesn't reproduce for me https://3v4l.org/LsQlR `var_dump($myl->point_spread)` gives back what?

Comment: Right ... it's such a simple thing that I have to be doing something somewhere else that is causing this behavior. I don't even know where to begin. Thanks for checking.

Comment: can you try to do `var_dump($myl->point_spread);` instead of an echo? `$myl->point_spread` may be a different type than a float actually

Comment: Doesn't reproduce for me either - I am getting your desired result of `-1.5`

Comment: Ah, now I see it is not a primitive type as I expected. `Point spread: -1 and 1.5
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => 1.5
)
`

Comment: Sorry that was print_r, not var_dump. Here is the var_dump `object(SimpleXMLElement)#166 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "1.5"
}
`

Comment: This makes sense since it is a string.

Answer (score 1):

In comments you write that **$myl->point_spread** is an SimpleXMLElement Object.
Try cast that value to float:

```
echo "Point spread: " . (((float)$myl->point_spread) * -1.0) . " and " . $myl->point_spread . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other helpful comments pointed out, a print_r or vardump reveals it was not a primitive float as I expected. Using floatvar( $myl->point_spread ) * -1.0 gives the expected result. Thanks all.

Comment: It looks the behavior of PHP +7.2.18 is to cast correctly. https://3v4l.org/Bm7C2